# The implementation of CherryPy's redirect

Tags: python, cherrypy, http-redirect

Why request redirects in CherryPy 3.x are implemented with `raise`, but not with `return`? Redirect operation may look like the following:

```
raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect('/index')
```

What CherryPy does when `raise` occurs? Why not return?

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically it is an implementation detail. Normally you return from CherryPy handler:

- `str`, `unicode`, `bytes` or iterable of them
- file-like object
- generator for streaming content

All these objects eventually become a response body. Redirects (3xx HTTP codes) and errors (`cherrypy.HTTPError`, 4xx and 5xx HTTP codes) either have no body or the body is set out of the handler (default of custom error pages). So it makes sense to distinguish them this way.

Also note that in Python exceptions are also a part of normal flow, e.g. `StopIteration`.